# Throw "net::ERR_ABORTED 404" error for Google's JSAPI

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, google-visualization, jsapi

In our solution, we reference the JSAPI offline file. However, it returns me "net::ERR_ABORTED 404" error when the page loads.

The error message is;

> https://www.google.com/uds/?file=visualization&v=1&packages=corechart
> net::ERR_ABORTED 404

Full console log:
[image]

This is how I referenced the js file.

[image]

However, This works when I use the online js (https://www.google.com/jsapi) instead of using an offline js file.

[image]

Note that I'm using jquery 1.11 version (also an offline file).

Any idea why it's not working when I use the offline js?

Comment: if you take a look at the [faq](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/faq) -- under __Can I use charts offline?__ -- it states --> _Our terms of service do not allow you to download the google.charts.load or google.visualization code to use offline._ -- in addition, `jsapi` is out of date and should no longer be used, see the [release notes](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/release_notes) for more info -- _All `jsapi` requests are now being redirected to the new loader._

Comment: @WhiteHat Thanks for the information. However, this was working until the 1st of July, 2020 morning. Then suddenly this is no longer working.

Comment: yes, pretty sure the last part of my comment was just implemented...

Comment: In addition to the jsapi redirect, the new thing that is happening now is that the uds server is turned off, so your local copy of the jsapi loader will no longer work.